# foreach loop through different models in the view model to display links

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I have two tables called objects and apartments, which are "connected" with foreign keys called `apartmentID` and `ObjectID`. My controller and model are pretty simple:

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Projekt.Models
{
    public class WrapperModel
    {

        public IEnumerable<Projekt.Models.objects> Objects { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Projekt.Models.apartments> Apartments { get; set; }


    }
}
```

And my controller is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Projekt.Models;

namespace Projekt.Controllers
{
    public class WrapperController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            WrapperModel wrapperModel = new WrapperModel();
            return View(wrapperModel);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to make a view that will use @foreach loop to:

- take a name of each Object, and link the name to its `Details.cshtml` page
- display Id of the apartment linking to its `Details.cshtml` page next to the Object link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first initialze your models

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // db is your DbContext or your entity that is represented your DB.
    YourDbContext db = new YourDbContext();

    WrapperModel wrapperModel = new WrapperModel();
    wrapperModel.Objects = db.Objects; // from your db
    wrapperModel.Apartments = db.Apartments;// from your db


    return View(wrapperModel);
}
```

view

```
@model WrapperModel 

@foreach(var item in Model.Objects)
{
    // list items in html elements
    @Html.ActionLink(item.name, "Details", "Controller", new { id = item.id })
}

@foreach(var item in Model.Apartments)
{
    // list items in html elements
    // link to details page
}
```

controller detail action

```
public ActionResult Details(int id){}
```

try something like above or modify that code for your expected result. And then ask more specific question

Comment: I dont understand the part "from your db". What is supposed to go there? Can you give me an example please?

Comment: Hi Is it possible to display this Model in for loop rather than foreach? when I try to submit data from the view to action result, I get null values