# How to loop thru view model for particular value using foreach and where

Tags: asp.net-mvc, foreach

(NUBE)  I am trying to loop thru a view model and show rows when a field has a particular value.  (IE In a Master/Detail model I have pulled all my orders in one list and all the detail in another. When the user picks the particular order from the first list I just want to iterate thru the detail list and show those line items for edit/delete purposes.

This code works from testing if I hardcode the value (2953) but I wish to pass a value and am not sure if Viewbag or razor is the way to go.  I would like to maintain a consistent framework throughout.

```
@foreach (var row in Model.SplitTankAssignmentItems.Where(x => x.MeterValueID == 2953) ) // row.splitTicketID) )
{
    <tr id="@row.SplitTankID>
    :
    :
    :
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [foreach loop through different models in the view model to display links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131826/foreach-loop-through-different-models-in-the-view-model-to-display-links)

Comment: @Bosco this is not a duplicate of the one you mention. This one is about a filter in the loop and how to get te value to filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ViewBag is exactly for this purpose.

On your control-action method you can set up the ViewBag and in your view you can read it.

**Controller**

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    :
    ViewBag.ValueToUse = 2953
    Return View(model);
}
```

**View**

```
@foreach (var row in Model.SplitTankAssignmentItems.Where(x => x.MeterValueID == (int)ViewBag.ValueToUse) ) // row.splitTicketID) )
{
    <tr id="@row.SplitTankID>
    :
    :
    :
    </tr>
}
```

Notes: Remeber to cast your ViewBag property to the type you need, and keep in mind that ViewBag is only for one call, usually to take information from controller to view. It won't stay from view to controller neither from an action method to action method (RedirectTo)

Comment: KodiakMx Thank you for the reinforcement.  Bill